# How to check how much of a line (percentage-wise) is covered by a polygon in arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy, polygon, line

I'm searching for an efficient way to check if a line is covered by a polygon (see image, this case should return 2x "true").

[image: line in polygon]

Right now I only check wether a line is within a buffer with

```
line.shape.within(buffer.shape)
```

But I want to know if a line is covered by a buffer with at least 50%.
As I'm doing this fully automated in a script with a lot of lines and buffers this should be fast.
Any tips?

current code snippet:

```
lines = arcpy.SearchCursor('lines')
for line in lines:
  bufferList = arcpy.SearchCursor("buffers")
  for buffer in bufferList:
    # here I want to check if a line is just covered by a buffer
    if line.shape.within(buffer.shape):
        if line.getValue('type') == buffer.getValue("type"):
          matchList = arcpy.InsertCursor('MatchList')
          matchList.insertRow(line)
          break
```

Comment: Would you be able to include a working code snippet to show what you mean, please?  Also, can you try again to include a picture, please?

Comment: Hi, changed image hoster and added a longer code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Intersect the lines with the polygons - then do a statistics on them to determine per line - how much length has the polygon attributes.  Then join that stats back to the original line table.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Hoped that there would be a built in method so I don't have to code it by myself. But your suggestion doesn't look too complicated.

Comment: It would be fairly straight forward to create you own python script with this as it only uses 3 geoprocessing tools.  If you are new to python scripting with Arcpy, try using model builder to create the process flow - then export it to a python script, this will get you a place to begin.